# Statistical test for aggregated proportion difference in difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, difference-in-difference

I would like to statistically test if difference in difference estimate is significant, but I do not know what test to use. I am trying to answer a question if war is affecting wellbeing. I have **survey data in 3 countries** before and after the war. They are as follow:

1. Country currently at war:

   a. Before war: 1000 (n11) responses, 50% responded "Yes" (r11)

   b. After war: 900 (n12) responses, 10% responded "Yes" (r12)
2. Neighboring country:

   a. Before war: 1200 (n21) responses, 40% responded "Yes" (r21)

   b. After war: 2000 (n22) responses, 25% responded "Yes" (r22)
3. Country far away from conflict:

   a. Before war: 1500 (n31) responses, 65% responded "Yes" (r31)

   b. After war: 1100 (n32) responses, 55% responded "Yes" (r32)

All countries had drop in reported well being in that period. All countries and periods have diffrent number of counts. I would like to determine that drop in country I vs country II and III. Country II is also affected but not as much. **Is there way to statistically prove it?**

**Would simple t-test of mean differences work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know how to treat in t-test different number of responses co I went with logistic regression. I believe it is right approach.

The code in Python is as follows (example of Country A vs Country B):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

# Country A
c1 = "A"
n11 = 1000 
n11_1 = 500
n12 = 900
n12_1 = 90
df_11 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Country": [c1] * n11,
     "Mental_health_symptoms": [0] * (n11 - n11_1) + [1] * n11_1,
     "Period": [0] * n11})
df_12 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Country": [c1] * n12,
     "Mental_health_symptoms": [0] * (n12 - n12_1) + [1] * n12_1,
     "Period": [1] * n12})
df_1 = pd.concat([df_11, df_12])

# Country B - first control
c2 = "B"
n21 = 1200
n21_1 = 450
n22 = 2000
n22_1 = 400
df_21 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Country": [c2] * n21,
     "Mental_health_symptoms": [0] * (n21 - n21_1) + [1] * n21_1,
     "Period": [0] * n21})
df_22 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Country": [c2] * n22,
     "Mental_health_symptoms": [0] * (n22 - n22_1) + [1] * n22_1,
     "Period": [1] * n22})
df_2 = pd.concat([df_21, df_22])


# Join
df_1_vs_2 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
# Change country to dummy
df_1_vs_2 = pd.get_dummies(df_1_vs_2, columns=["Country"])
# change into int
df_1_vs_2["Country_A"] = df_1_vs_2["Country_A"].astype(int)
# add interaction
df_1_vs_2["Period*Country_A"] = df_1_vs_2["Period"] * df_1_vs_2["Country_A"]
# drop columns
df_1_vs_2 = df_1_vs_2.drop(columns=["Country_B", ])


# model
y = df_1_vs_2["Mental_health_symptoms"]
X = df_1_vs_2[["Period", "Country_A", "Period*Country_A"]]
model_1_vs_2 = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
model_1_vs_2.summary()
```

**All variables were statistically significant, so the difference in country A vs Country B is higher (as the interaction variable is significant)**